# Integral of exponential with absolute exponent

Tags: integration

I am trying to find the integral of

\begin{align}
        f(y) 
     &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
        \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
            e^{- a \left|| x - y \right||^2} dx \, dy \\
     &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
        \int\limits_{-\infty}^{y} 
        e^{a \left( y - x \right)^2} dx \, dy
      + \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
        \int\limits_{y}^{\infty} 
        e^{a \left( x - y \right)^2} dx \, dy
\end{align}

but I'm having trouble finding the solution to each part. I'd really appreciate help if anyone knows how to do it? I'm guessing there's an $\operatorname{erf}()$ function in there somewhere.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cheers,

Katie

Comment: Absolute exponent? It seems to me a norm...

Comment: Hi José. Does it being a norm change the way I approach the integral? I'm not sure why that's significant...

Comment: I think I can probably work it out now I've found this... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138154/integral-with-exp-and-erf?rq=1